# How to pass Laravel data into Vue root instance with Laravel Mix Setup

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

So I am using Laravel 5.5. I have a data coming from my Controller and I want to pass it to my root vue instance not the component.

So for example I have the Dashboard Controller which has a data of "users"

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function index(){

       $user = User::find(1);

       return view('index', compact('user'));

    }

}
```

I am using Larave mix on my project setup. So my main js file is the app.js. That "$user" data I need to pass on the root Vue instance. Which is located in app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#dashboard',

    data: { 
        // I want all the data from my controller in here.
    },

});
```

Comment: Use axios (ajax) call from the Vue to call your route that returns data

Comment: during the mouting event?

Comment: Yeah that is what I would do. I am using something similar now in one of my projects. It is a bit of a pain to wire up but it works well once its done!

Comment: @IamCavic thank you so much for you help I will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an API call to get data (using *axios* or else), you could simply try this :

```
JavaScript::put(['user' => $user ]);
```

This will, by default, bind your JavaScript variables to a "footer" view. You should load your `app.js` after this footer view (or modify param `bind_js_vars_to_this_view`).

In `app.js` :

```
data: { 
    user: user
}
```

Read more : https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: I tried using that but I can't get the data from app.js. It seems that is only available if you are inside the blade files.

Comment: No, make sure your app.js is loaded after, you could set `bind_js_vars_to_this_view` param.

Comment: Thanks I have a mistake on my end. I didn't put the right path to my partial footer file

Answer (score 1):

I would make a request to fetch the user's data as has been suggested.

Alternatively, you can add a prop to the dashboard component in index.blade.php and set the user like `<dashboard :user="{{ $user }}"></dashboard>`. You'll probably want to `json_encode` or `->toArray()` the $user variable.

Then within the dashboard component you can set data values based on the prop.

```
props: ['user'],
data () {
    return {
        user: this.user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by placing a reference on the `window` Object in the `<head>` of my layout file, and then picking that reference up with a mixin that can be injected into any component.

> TLDR SOLUTION

**.env**

```
GEODATA_URL="https://geo.some-domain.com"
```

**config/geodata.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'url' => env('GEODATA_URL')
];
```

**resources/views/layouts/root.blade.php**

```
<head>
    <script>
        window.geodataUrl = "{{ config('geodata.url') }}";
    </script>
</head>
```

**resources/js/components/mixins/geodataUrl.js**

```
const geodataUrl = {
    data() {
        return {
            geodataUrl: window.geodataUrl,
        };
    },
};

export default geodataUrl;
```

**usage**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a :href="geodataUrl">YOLO</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import geodataUrl from '../mixins/geodataUrl';

export default {
    name: 'v-foo',

    mixins: [geodataUrl],

    data() {
        return {};
    },

    computed: {},

    methods: {},
};
</script>
```

> END TLDR SOLUTION

If you want, you can use a global mixin instead by adding this to your `app.js` entrypoint:

```
Vue.mixin({
    data() {
        return {
            geodataUrl: window.geodataUrl,
        };
    },
});
```

I would not recommend using this pattern, however, for any sensitive data because it is sitting on the `window` Object.

I like this solution because it doesn't use any extra libraries, and the chain of code is very clear. It passes the grep test, in that you can search your code for `"window.geodataUrl"` and see everything you need to understand how and why the code is working.

That consideration is important if the code may live for a long time and another developer may come across it.

However, `JavaScript::put([])` is in my opinion, a decent utility that can be worth having, but in the past I have disliked how it can be extremely difficult to debug if a problem happens, because you cannot see where in the codebase the data comes from.

Imagine you have some Vue code that is consuming `window.chartData` that came from `JavaScript::put([ 'chartData' => $user->chartStuff ])`. Depending on the number of references to `chartData` in your code base, it could take you a very long time to discover which PHP file was responsible for making `window.chartData` work, especially if you didn't write that code and the next person has no idea `JavaScript::put()` is being used.

In that case, I recommend putting a comment in the code like:

```
/* data comes from poop.php via JavaScript::put */
```

Then the person can search the code for `"JavaScript::put"` and quickly find it. Keep in mind "the person" could be yourself in 6 months after you forget the implementation details.

It is always a good idea to use Vue component prop declarations like this:

```
props: {
    chartData: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
    },
},
```

My point is, if you use `JavaScript::put()`, then Vue cannot detect as easily if the component fails to receive the data. Vue must assume the data is there on the window Object at the moment in time it refers to it. Your best bet may be to instead create a GET endpoint and make a fetch call in your created/mounted lifecycle method.

I think it is important to have an explicit contract between Laravel and Vue when it comes to getting/setting data.

In the interest of helping you as much as possible by giving you options, here is an example of making a fetch call using ES6 syntax sugar:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/charts/{user}/coolchart', 'UserController@getChart')->name('user.chart');
```

**app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php**

```
public function getChart(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // do stuff
    $data = $user->chart;

    return response()->json([
        'chartData' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

Anywhere in Vue, especially a created lifecycle method:

```
created() {
    this.handleGetChart();
},

methods: {
    async handleGetChart() {
        try {
            this.state = LOADING;
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/charts/${this.user.id}/coolchart`);

            if (typeof data !== 'object') {
                throw new Error(`Unexpected server response. Expected object, got: ${data}`);
            }

            this.chartData = data.chartData;
            this.state = DATA_LOADED;
        } catch (err) {
            this.state = DATA_FAILED;
            throw new Error(`Problem getting chart data: ${err}`);
        }
    },
},
```

That example assumes your Vue component is a Mealy finite state machine, whereby the component can only be in one state at any given time, but it can freely switch between states.

I'd recommend using such states as computed props:

```
computed: {
    isLoading() { return (this.state === LOADING); },
    isDataLoaded() { return (this.state === DATA_LOADED); },
    isDataFailed() { return (this.state === DATA_FAILED); },
},
```

With markup such as:

```
<div v-show="isLoading">Loading...</div>
<v-baller-chart v-if="isDataLoaded" :data="chartData"></v-baller-chart>
<button v-show="isDataFailed" type="button" @click="handleGetChart">TRY AGAIN</button>
```